# angular routing .otherwise resets service variable?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm using a service to store an array so it's accessible while routing.

It works for my two routes:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/main',{
            templateUrl: '/templates/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/print', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/print.html',
            //template: '<div> {{ x }}</div>',
            controller: 'PrintController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/main',
        });
```

So I can switch between /main and /print and all the data is available.

But when I go to any other URL (hence triggering the .otherwise) the data is lost. I print the length of the array and it's '0' (just to be sure that it's actually gone).

I understood that services are kept during the applicaiton life so I'd expect that MyService.myArray it's kept through the routing.

for reference here's the relevant part of the MainController:

```js
// pulls .json file (recipes) from dropbox
// when we return from the dropbox auth call we will have a "code" variable in the URL
if($routeParams.code){
        // get dropbox token using the code
        dropbox.getToken($routeParams.code).then(function(token){
        // getting the actual file from dropbox
        dropbox.pullRecipes().then(function(data){
            $scope.recipes = data; // assigne it tot he controller scope
            dropbox.recipesArray = data; // set it on the dropbox factory so it's available to other controllers
            console.log("Recipes successfully pulled from dropbox: "+$scope.recipes.length); 
        });
        }, function(err){
            console.log("Errors aquiring the token");
            console.log (err);
        });
    }


    // I'd expect this to be full, but it's actually empty
    $scope.recipes = dropbox.recipesArray;
    console.log(dropbox.recipesArray.length); // 0
```

Comment: if this service is called by the controller MainController .. then it's normal that it's reset once the controller is destroyed ? did you try using this service in an angular.module('app').run(function(dropbox) {..}); maybe then it won't be reset

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I declared the module like this: `var app = angular.module("recipeManager", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);
` and the factory is created like this: `app.factory('dropbox', ['$http', etcetc]){// factory code}`.

On the controller I have: `app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'dropbox', etc) `

Comment: I think the problem comes from recipesArray how it's used.. you should make a closure and return a function and not the variable

Comment: I think I found out why.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason:

when entering a URL on the browser the app is re-initialized, so is the controller and also the service and so all teh data is lost and needed to be pulled again.